# How to get a tilde over i without the dot

Tags: tipa, tilde, remove

I am using the package `tipa`, with the {`\~i`} command but I have also tried the mathmode command `\tilde{i}` as well. Both commands produce the following:

[image]

I would like to have a tilde that takes the place of the dot, as opposed to being placed over it. This represents nasality in linguistics, and it ought to look like this:

[image]

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: are you commited to pdflatex/tipa or can you use luatex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No special package is needed, just use `\~` or type `ĩ`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

\~{\i} ĩ
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat of a quick answer, and obviousy not the best: use the `dotlessi` package.

```
\documentclass[preview, border=.2cm
]{standalone}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{dotlessi}

\begin{document}
\~\dotlessi
\end{document}
```

[image]